# robot: command not found in Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, macos, robotframework

I installed python3 and robot framework from command line. When I run robot test cases. I keep getting an error, "robot: command not found". Below is pip list and pip3 list.

```
Sindoo:~ XXXXXXXXX$ pip list
Package                        Version
------------------------------ ----------
appdirs                        1.4.3
certifi                        2020.4.5.1
distlib                        0.3.0
filelock                       3.0.12
importlib-metadata             1.6.0
pip                            20.1
pipenv                         2018.11.26
robotframework                 3.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.3.1
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     46.1.3
six                            1.14.0
urllib3                        1.25.9
virtualenv                     20.0.20
virtualenv-clone               0.5.4
wheel                          0.34.2
zipp                           3.1.0

Sindoo:~ XXXXXXXXX$ pip3 list
Package                        Version
------------------------------ ----------
appdirs                        1.4.3
certifi                        2020.4.5.1
distlib                        0.3.0
filelock                       3.0.12
importlib-metadata             1.6.0
pip                            20.1
pipenv                         2018.11.26
robotframework                 3.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 3.3.1
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     46.1.3
six                            1.14.0
urllib3                        1.25.9
virtualenv                     20.0.20
virtualenv-clone               0.5.4
wheel                          0.34.2
zipp                           3.1.0
```

When I try to check robot --version. I get an error.

```
robot --version

-bash: robot: command not found
```

May I know Why robot is not working?

Comment: Please try this: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/2430#issuecomment-242036887

Comment: The above link did not help. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `python -m robot` or `python3 -m robot` instead.